# Change/reset the default display

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi

I will have a difficult part of explaining the problem, but ...

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, and inside it a docker that heavily uses the graphic card, which is Nvidia one.

Due to swap file being full [I'm 32GB+8GB for swap on SSD] the machine stuck while I'm in the docker. This is usually happens when I'm trying to compile a heavy C++ project and do not ensure the swap is free [so I suppose the OS is having a hard time to detect where to get additional memory].

The problem starts, when I have missed the point in time when the swap file is full and the machine is stuck [or hard reset for that matter].

Once rebooted, Ubuntu is not able to run application on display :1 which is the graphic card. Though the HDMI cable is still connected and the GUI is displayed.

The working approach is to shut down the machine. Connect HDMI to motherboard. Start Ubuntu. Then shut down and re-connect back to video card.

After that the problem is gone.

However, this only works if I have a physical access to my machine. Which is unfortunately not a case at the moment.

I have the following output of
`xrandr -q --display :0`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1080     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

and `xrandr -q --display :1`

```
Can't open display :1
```

At this moment my screen is connected to video card and it seems, this is DISPLAY :1. However, starting things on that display does not work as expected.

For example, running `DISPLAY=:1 firefox` outputs the following:

```
Gtk-Message: 09:01:12.579: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
Error: cannot open display: :1
```

Running firefox in a natural way produces the following graphics:
[image: firefox looks like this]

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14d8
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14db
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14db
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14db
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14da
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14dd
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14dd
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 71)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 14e7
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2782 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22bc (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f4 (rev 01)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:0b.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:0c.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
04:0d.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f5 (rev 01)
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
0e:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f7 (rev 01)
0f:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43f6 (rev 01)
10:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 164e (rev c1)
10:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1640
10:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] VanGogh PSP/CCP
10:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b6
10:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b7
10:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
11:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b8
```

What is the problem, and how can I solve it by executing some commands without resorting to the workaround I have used up until now?

Comment: I am confused. This appears to be more than one question.

Comment: If I would know what is the problem, I probably would know to at least search for a solution for it.

Comment: Ok, so am I correct to understand that your problem is with X11 displays not Docker? Why are you putting the `DISPLAY=:1` in front of firefox, while showing us the xrandr of :0? What happens if you start `firefox` naturally without the `DISPLAY=:1`?

Comment: @DanielT, well firefox started naturally looks bad. I will update

Comment: Do you have multiple GPUs? What's your `lspci`? Have you tried disabling hardware acceleration in firefox?

Comment: firefox is the least of the problem, I need GPU to run an app, and since it runs over docker, and the later fails to start [cause I suppose it is dependent on the right Nvidia working drivers] I'm asking to pinpoint the problem to start looking for answers

Comment: Docker CUDA can run headlessly. Therefore it is unrelated to your HDMI plug and DISPLAY=:1 problems